# ms access 2007 auto decrease value as date change

Tags: ms-access-2007

i was wondering if its possible to do this in access.

I was trying to make a value decrease automatically as the date change.

For example, i have this period of time lets say 3 month starting from today. Today 27 december 2015, the value of the book is 50, then on the next day 28 december, the value of the book is 48 and so on. After it has been 3 month, the value of the book will be 0.

so, is it possible to do this in access? and if its possible, how do i do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Dim IntroPrice As Currency
Dim PublishingDate As Date
Dim Period As Integer
Dim CurrentPrice As Currency
Dim Days As Integer

IntroPrice = 50
PublishingDate = DateSerial(2015, 12, 27)
Period = 90
Days = DateDiff("d", PublishingDate, Date)
If Days >= Period Then
    CurrentPrice = 0
Else
    CurrentPrice = IntroPrice * (90 - Days) / 90
End If
```

Comment: thank you, i will try to do this first. also, how do i get access to detect the date since the number of days for each month is different.

Comment: `Date` does return the current date.

Comment: can i do it in query?

Comment: You can use the code both at a button-click and - as a function - in a query like any other function. Since you ask, I'll recommend you to look up and study some intro tutorials on _Microsoft Access_ and _VBA_.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works perfect. I want to ask though about the DateSerial. Can't it get the date from the other field? for example DateSerial([Date_From]) is this function wrong?

Comment: No. You would just use: `PublishingDate = [Date_From]`

Comment: okay, thank you so much for your help. It works perfect!. Just like i want it to be. :)